# Filtering Many-to-Many relationship by Relationship field in Django

Tags: django, filtering, django-orm

I'm trying to filter many-to-many relationship by some **through Class** field.

Quoting the Django documentation, i will explain my goal

```
class Person(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
      members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
      person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
      group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
      date_joined = models.DateField()
      invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

In this example my goal sould be filter many to many relationship and obtain only the **Person** who has joined some **Group** starting from certain date (**date_joined field**).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can [query across relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) with the django ORM (or in this case the reverse relationship):

```
person = Person.objects.filter(
    membership__group=example_group,
    membership__date_joined__gte=example_date
)
```

Comment: It's a little tricky than we can't do `Group.objects.filter(members__date_joined=...)`, all the queries are made from explicit fields in the model. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
person = example_group.members.filter(
    membership__date_joined__gte=example_date
)
```