# Django Filtering Many-to-Many relationship without ManyToManyField "through" relationship

Tags: django, django-models

Given these models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class Project(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

class EventProject(models.Model):
      event= models.ForeignKey(Event)
      project= models.ForeignKey(Project)
```

Is there a way to get all the `Events` for each `Project` like this: with the property `project.events = [<array of Event>]`?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891302/filtering-many-to-many-relationship-by-relationship-field-in-django), however one of the tables has the `members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')` relationship so it's easier to do. I can't do as in the related question and add a relationship as I cannot change the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straight Forward

```
Event.objects.filter(eventproject__project=project)
```

Filtering through ForeignKey works both forward and backward in Django. You can use the model name in lower case for backward filtering.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: Argh thanks! I was  writing `event_project__project=project` (with an underscore) so all this time it was working, thanks again!